# How to create such layout for each row of Android Listview?(Tricky Layout :) )

Tags: android

please help me to create the following xml layout for the row of my listview

[image]

Here the Text is written in a textview and remaining 5 boxes are 5 different ImageView, and the Images should be clickable.

Main problem is how thetext comes over the images.

Answer (score 1):

As per Peter Knego's answer, `RelativeLayout` is what you want for overlapping Views, but I suspect you will find it hard to get the onClick events for images underneath the text.

You may need to do a custom layout class that extends `RelativeLayout` and draws your text manually from [`dispatchDraw()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#dispatchDraw%28android.graphics.Canvas%29).

Answer (score 0):

Try using [RelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout-objects.html#relativelayout).

Comment: ya we are trying the reltive but the problem is textview content cannot be overlapped with imageViews

Comment: Then use FrameLayout which overlaps all children. Inside it put two RelativeLayouts which will overlap. Use one for text, the other for images.